# QGIS 2.10 Edit shapefiles saving only once

Tags: shapefile, editing, qgis-2.10

I'm have some trouble while editing my shapefiles. I can save only once.

So what I have to do is to save as another file, add to QGIS and edit again. Save as another file... And on and on...

Does anyone have a clue to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Caio! Do you receive any error messages when you try to save it multiple times? Does QGIS crash? Are you working in Windows or Mac?

Comment: Not a single message. I just click save and everything returns as nothing happened. Using Windows

Comment: Do you have full write access on the target folder? Usually you may use the `Browse ...` bar to select a target different from the programmes folder.